# Storing signed or unsigned value in a transaction ledger table

Tags: php, mysql, unsigned, signed

Imagine a transaction table..

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` ENUM('buy','sell') NOT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `currency` ENUM('eur','usd') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now if I need to sum all entries and return a total, I would do the following

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN `type` = 'buy' THEN `amount` ELSE -`amount`
    END) AS `total`,
    `currency`
  FROM `transaction`
GROUP BY `currency`;
```

Now imagine a `SIGNED` `amount`.

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `total` FROM `transaction` GROUP BY `currency`;
```

Seems simpler, right? But somehow feels like I'm missing something and things could become complicated later on, especially if I need to process the data later with PHP.

I would much appreciate any comments on pros and cons using signed and unsigned numbers.

Comment: @mkaatman this question is a poor fit over there, see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260). Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)

Comment: With minor rewording the question could be made acceptable. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @mkaatman basically I want to know, if I miss a point that could make things complicated with this or that schema. Shall I remove the "pros and cons" sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Using an unsigned value originally allowed you to store larger values (~2X larger) in the same space in cases where you do not need negative values.

For your situation, I'd drop the unsigned on the decimal column, and represent the values as they should be. Doing the math in your queries as in the example will impact performance, maybe significantly for large queries.

It's almost always better to represent data without qualifiers, but instead as it is in reality. Imagine the impact on performance if one day you also have to add currency conversion.

Lastly, with your current implementation, how would you represent a credit vs debit? For example, if there is a refund on a sale, you have no way to store an "un-sell" transaction.

Comment: What do you mean by "add currency conversion" how would this impact on the performance? Do you mean by "data without qualifiers" that I should remove "buy" and "sell" and represent the type of a variable only by the sign (+/-)?

Comment: By "add currency conversion" I was using that as an example of some future need that would require doing math on the "real" value. By "data without qualifiers", yes, I would not use another field to indicate the sign of a value. You might still use the buy and sell value to indicate the type of transaction, but not the sign of the value.